# Using Range.Find in VBA to find only the previous value x?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use the Range.Find method in VBA to locate the closest previous row number that has a "true" value.

For example, in Column X, there will be a "true" value (row 35), 10 rows with "false," and then "true" again (row 46).

When I get to row 46 in my loop, I need to do a range.find and return row 35.

---

The code I am using is this:

```
Worksheets("Data").Cells.Find(True, searchorder:=xlByColumns, searchdirection:=xlNext).Row
```

What is happening is that I am only finding either the very first "true" value (in this case, row 2), or the very last "true" value (row 24,xxx), as I vary search direction.

What can I do to find only the previous-most "true" value?

Comment: This can be done with a pair of [Range.Find method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx) and [Range.FindNext method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196143.aspx) but how do you plan to stop the forever loop?

Comment: Every time you find `True`, store the row in a variable. The next time you will know what was the last row without even needing to use `.Find`...

Comment: You need to specify the `After` cell to be row 46 and use `xlPrevious` as the direction.

Comment: @SiddharthRout I'd rather use find, because there are an unknown number of variables.  How can you write code to create a new, unique variable every time you find "x" value anyways?  I guess I could use an array, but again.  I would rather use one variable with a stored row number, because the total number of "true" values is not known.

Comment: @Jeeped what loop?  I didn't put the loop in my code into my original post.  It is not infinite.

Comment: Sorry. When you described going to row 35 then row 46 then back to row 35 I inferred that you were looping through a Find TRUE. I guess I really do not understand the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the previous row with True by using the `After` argument in the `Find` method combined with `xlPrevious` as the `SearchDirection`. I have updated the code to add it into a loop, based on your comments.

Since you posted your code, I have edited my answer into your code.

```
Sub Main()

Dim iCurRow As Long
Dim iCounter As Long
Dim iLastRow As Long
Dim iTempRow As Long
Dim iPreviousRow As Long
Dim iChangeCol As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Worksheets("Data")

With ws

    iChangeCol = .Cells.Find(what:="Change Over?", searchorder:=xlByColumns, searchdirection:=xlNext).Column

    iLastRow = .Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row

    iPreviousRow = 2

    For iCounter = 3 To iLastRow

        If .Cells(iCounter, iChangeCol).Value = True Then

            iTempRow = .Cells.Find(what:=True, After:=.Cells(iCounter, iChangeCol), searchorder:=xlByColumns, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row

            iPreviousRow = iTempRow

        End If

    Next iCounter

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I have not tried this yet, but I would have to change myCell every time I find a new true value to be the current range.  Is there a cleaner method?  This may work, let me try it.

Comment: It could be cleaner, but I don't know exactly how you are looping to find a `new true value`. If you already have the way to find your `True` value, then you make that cell = myCell.

Comment: Well, I essentially am looping through my rows of data and using a counter variable to increment the row #.  So, in psuedo-code, if the cell with row number of the current counter variable and column number that corresponds to my change over data is equal to true, then execute this code.  This is where I am trying to find the previous true value, so I know both rows and can find out how many hours we were running x product.

Comment: I also ran into a problem trying to set the range using range(cells(x,y),cells(x,y)).

Comment: I edited my code to incorporate yours. You basically were not following the guidance since the beginning of using `After` and `xlPrevious`.

Comment: Seems to work.  It does find the row above the "current" true value.  But I have the code working now.  Carry on.

Answer (score 1):

This short snippet uses both the [Range.Find method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx) and [Range.FindNext method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196143.aspx) to cycle through all matching cells in column X.

```
Sub rings_true()
    Dim fnd As Range
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")   `<~~ set this worksheet reference properly
        With .Columns(24)
            Set fnd = .Find(What:="TRUE", after:=.Cells(.Rows.Count), _
                             LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                             SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
            Do While Not fnd Is Nothing
                If MsgBox("Currently at " & fnd.Address(0, 0) & Chr(10) & "exit now...?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion) = vbYes Then
                    Exit Do
                Else
                    Set fnd = .FindNext(after:=fnd)
                End If
            Loop
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

The current cell address is reported through a [MsgBox function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa445082(v=vs.60).aspx). The same MsgBox offers the user the opportunity to break the loop.

Additional error control might include confirming at least one matching value in column X before entering into the loop.

Answer (score 1):

There are **multiple arguments to put into the `Find` method**, regarding what you told us, I suggest that you use :

1. `After:=.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1)` to start from the bottom of the column
2. `LookIn:=xlValues`
3. `LookAt:=xlWhole`
4. `SearchOrder:=xlByRows` to look row by row (instead of column by column)
5. `SearchDirection:=xlPrevious` to look "back", from bottom to top
6. `MatchCase:=False`
7. `SearchFormat:=False`

And furthermore, you can **use the `.Find` method into a specific range**, so rather than `Worksheets("Data").Cells.Find(...`, you should use `Worksheets("Data").Range("X:X").Find(...` to look only in the column X.

Here is your amended code :

```
Sub test_ilarson007()
Dim FirstAddress As String, PreviousMatch As Range, cF As Range

Worksheets("Data").Activate
With Worksheets("Data").Range("X:X")
    'First, define properly the Find method
    Set cF = .Find(What:=True, _
                After:=ActiveCell, _
                LookIn:=xlValues, _
                LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                MatchCase:=False, _
                SearchFormat:=False)

    'If there is a result,
    If Not cF Is Nothing Then
        FirstAddress = cF.Address
        MsgBox "The row containing the previous 'True' in Column X is : " & cF.Row
        'keep looking with FindNext method : Not usefull for your example
        Do
            Set PreviousMatch = cF
            Set cF = .FindNext(cF)
            '-------------------------------------------------------------
            '----Place instructions to execute on the matched cell/row/...
            'First match (i.e. Row 46 in your example)
            MsgBox PreviousMatch.Row 'Should display 46 (then 35, then ??)
            'Second match (i.e. Row 35 in your example)
            MsgBox cf.Row 'Should display 35 (then ??, then ??)


            '-------------------------------------------------------------
        'Look until you find again the first result
        Loop While Not cF Is Nothing And cF.Address <> FirstAddress
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: This is assuming that I am activating cells when I find them.  I am simply using a counter from my overall loop to identify the row # of the cells (column known).  I need to use the row numbers of the current and previous true value, so that I can place a formula in an adjacent column and take the difference in time of a different adjacent column's cells that line up with the previous true value, and one row above the current true value.

Comment: Ok take a look at the edit, I changed to include the loop and added a new Range variable so that while looping you have both the first (`PreviousMatch`) and second match (`cF`). Be careful, *row of first match > row of second match* as we start from the bottom of the column (that can be changed)

Comment: Are you finding both the current true value as well as the previous with this code?  If I am following you correctly, I could set the Range of cF based on known information at this point in my code (I have the column of interest identified at the beginning, and the current value of my loop counter minus one will be the row number of interest).

Comment: Yes, as I store the previously found cell in the variable `PreviousMatch` and the *newly* found cell in `cF`, you can have both lines in the code to work with them (take a look a the edit, I added 2 MsgBox)